# How can I Form timer stop from other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer, restart

I'm using Form timer fired by serialport datareceived. Sometimes timer should stopped by user but timer doesn't stop but it doesn't

Here is my summarized code.

```
private delegate void MessageDelegate(string str);
private MessageDelegate addmsg;
private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!StopRequests_DataReceivedRunning) //initially false and set true by StopMenuItem_Click()
    {
       addmsg = new MessageDelegate(InterpretMessage);
       //...get seriaport string...
       Invoke(addmsg, new object[] { strDataReceived.ToString() });
     }
}
private void InterpretMessage(string ReceivedMessage)
{
  //...do something
  if(condition is met)
    {
      timer.Interval = 10000
      timer.Start();
    }

}
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(timer.Enabled.ToString()); ;
  //<do-work>
}
private void StopMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer.Enabled = false;
  StopRequests_DataReceivedRunning = true;
}
```

If I click StopMenuItem during running of timer, it doesn't stop and finally raise timer_Tick event(console output is true). Also, it looks timer restart at the moment, timer.Enabled = false.

Edit: I added more codes.

Comment: Setting `Timer.Enabled` to false (same as calling `Timer.Stop()`) stops raising the `Timer.Elapsed` event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0). Your code doesn't show this event being handled so it isn't clear what you mean by 'it doesn't stop'.

Comment: If it gets a message from serialport, then it starts again!

Comment: What is the type of the `timer`? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`?

Comment: @PoulBak  I checked routine again and you're right. I blocked refiring and solved the problem!